# variation of binary search

Tags: python, binary-search

Say that the target isn't in the list. Instead of outputting `-1`, I want it to output the rightmost value that's less than the target, followed by the next value (if there is one). In other words, I want to see the gap where the target *would* be.

If there was a list `[1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9]` and I was looking for `5`, instead of outputting `-1` I want it to output `[4, 7]`. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, how would you implement a _regular_ binary search? It shouldn't take much of a modification from that, but you'll need a starting point.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74844003/edit) your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question seems to be vague and also doesn't include any code that you have tried

Comment: If the target isn't found, then find the rightmost value in the list that is less than the target, and return that value and its successor (if there is one).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) to find the insertion point for 5 using binary search, and then take the elements before and after that point:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> a = [1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i = bisect.bisect(a, 5)
>>> a[i-1:i+1]
[4, 7]
```